# How found brackets in a field string apache solr

Tags: json, solr

I am trying found all docs countains brackets on apache solr fields but I don´t know how found it,
I am trying with diferents examples but I don´t got results.

Examples docs:

```
{
id:1,
"nombre_texto":["[[MIN009NOIHDWE9351110D22.pdf]]"],
"archivo_tipo_nombre_texto":["[[Facturas Electronicas]]"]
}
```

Query: nombre_texto:"[["

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

in the fq search field try

```
nombre_texto:*[[*
```

this will search for "[[" with anything before or after it
[image]

Comment: result:{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "fq":"nombre_txt:*[[*",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1600662030473"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.parser.ParseException"],
    "msg":"org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'nombre_txt:*[[*': Encountered \"<EOF>\" at line 1, column 15.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"TO\" ...\n    <RANGE_QUOTED> ...\n    <RANGE_GOOP> ...\n    ",
    "code":400}}